# Chrome Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED)

Tags: google-chrome

When I enter the page:
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

I am getting Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED). But when I try to use FF, it works.

BTW, the facebook social widgets (which load this file) is not working on Chrome. I have the latest version.

What is wrong?

Comment: BTW, it works on Chromes from other PCs. And I'm using Win7 Ultimate 64 bits.

Answer (score 31):

This can happen when an HTTP request's headers claim that the content is gzip encoded, but it isn't. This happened to me just now on Wordpress where I had WP Super Cache's gzip compression enabled. Normally it worked fine, but when I dumped some content out before the page was properly generated, it screwed up the compression.

Resolution if you're the web developer: turn off gzip encoding or make sure the content is in fact encoded.

Comment: +1 for this as an explanation- I've run into this problem w/ Amazon cloudfront + s3 with Django 1.4 when `AWS_IS_GZIPPED` was set to `True` in application configuration.

Comment: I have oscommerce setup. Turning  off gzip solved the issue. Was wondering how ideally I could enable real gzip encoding for the website instead. Must be configurable from htaccess or PHP

Comment: I ran into this error when using Apache's mod_proxy_html. The backend server was gzipping but the proxy was not. To fix I used mod_headers with the line: RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

Answer (score 7):

Using [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/), go to `/config/config.php` and set

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

And this worked for me, but the real solution should be inside apache configurations

Comment: where is `/config`?

Comment: I don't think your answer relates at all to the question.

Comment: it worked for me, this is the issue I got.

Comment: I already have that set to false, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 4):

I reinstalled Chrome and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Reason also could be your antivirus web shield. In my case I had issues with a lot of css files, so I set exclusion rule for css files. Try turning the shield off for a minute, reload the page you have problems with (use full reload, Ctrl+F5).
If it works, try to exclude js files (you can also do it for css files before you even get such problems with them) from your web shield

Answer (score 2):

I had this affecting all web pages (not even Google would load).

Closing Chrome and starting it again solved it for me so far. If it turns out to be a recurring problem, I’ll try re-installing Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I had a client using an older theme that used php and declared: `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`

Thing is Apache was config'd the server gzip'd content so the content was compressed "twice" this caused the same error in chrome for me.